# Javascript - set context2d Image as background for canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, fabricjs

I'm using the below code to set the good quality image as background for canvas. If I set the image directly as background, it was working. But the image quality isn't good. So I'm using another canvas to have a good quality image and then I need to set as background. I'm using `fabricjs`

```
var _img = new Image();
_img.src = img_base64;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

_img.onload = function(){
    // set size proportional to image
    canvas.height = canvas.width * (_img.height / _img.width);

    // resize to 50%
    var oc = document.createElement('canvas'),
    octx = oc.getContext('2d');
    oc.width = _img.width * 0.5;
    oc.height = _img.height * 0.5;
    octx.drawImage(_img, 0, 0, oc.width, oc.height);

    octx.drawImage(oc, 0, 0, oc.width * 0.5, oc.height * 0.5);

    ctx.drawImage(oc, 0, 0, oc.width * 0.5, oc.height * 0.5, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // Should be an instance of fabric.image
    var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(ctx, {
        width: canvas.width,
        height: canvas.height
    });
    console.log(imgInstance);

    canvas.setBackgroundImage(imgInstance, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), {
        width: canvas.width ,
        height: canvas.height,
        /*originX: 'left',
        originY: 'top'*/
        // Needed to position backgroundImage at 0/0
    });
};
```

The error is

> Argument 1 of CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage could not be converted to any of: HTMLImageElement, SVGImageElement, HTMLCanvasElement, HTMLVideoElement, ImageBitmap

I'm using base64 actually. but for the fiddle, I'm using direct path

Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pdct8nqz/)

Edit : I see the image rendering in my local, But I need to set it as background.

Comment: You want to set as canvas background right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. From the `ctx`

Comment: If you directly load that image as background i dont think there is quality issue. Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pdct8nqz/1/)

Comment: No, This is the original image. http://tigeensolutions.com/test/sample.jpg

Comment: **typo:** `new fabric.Image(ctx,` Image constructor accepts either an HTMLImageElement, or an HTMLCanvasElement (and possibly all the other ones accepted by drawImage) or a string representing the id of such an element in the doc. `ctx` is a CanvasRenderingContext2D, which is not supported by this method. I guess you meant `new fabric.Image(oc,`...

Comment: This isn't a typo. I tried that object, even if I use oc also, same issue. The question is different

Comment: This is a typo, `new fabric.Image(oc,` is what you want. (changed the image source because your server is so slow... https://jsfiddle.net/pdct8nqz/2/)

Comment: You should really give us a screenshot of what is good quality vs bad quality to get more detail

Answer (score 0):

The only reason why an image quality may not be good is because there is an high downscale/upscale factor.

Downscaling is good with image and css elements, while is bad when done on drawImage on the canvas, since the canvas use a nearest neighbour resize.

Other than that, quality of the image is preserved.

Fabricjs try to help on this offering resize filters.

You can apply a resize filter to an image when you load it so that then you work with an image of the dimension you need and that match 1:1 your canvas pixels.
Be aware that then if you export in higher resolution you will not get back the original quality of the image.